# How to initialize object of a class if the values are stored in a .txt file in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

How to initialize an object of a class if the values are stored in a .txt file in C++

I'm Making A Data Management System Which has 3 Options:-

1. Add a new student.
2. View a student's information.
3. Delete a student.

And the code looks something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//Struct Containing The Service Numbers
struct Service
{
    string Add="1";
    string View="2";
    string Delete="3";
};

//The Main Student Class

class Student
{
public:

    //Bio Of Student
    
    string Name;
    int Age;
    string Gender;
    int Class;
    
    //Constructer Insitializing The Bio Variable
    
    Student(string Name,string Gender,int Age,int Class)
    {
        this->Name=Name;
        this->Gender=Gender;
        this->Age=Age;
        this->Class=Class;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"•Add A Student [PRESS 1]\n•View Student's Information [PRESS 2]\n•Delete A Student [PRESS 3]"<<endl;

//Goto Statement If Input Is Incorrect

Err:
    cout<<"Which Service Do You Want To Access :";
    int Age;
    int Class;
    string Serv;
    cin>>Serv;
    Service ser;
    
    //Bunch Of If Statement
    
    if(Serv!=ser.Add && Serv!=ser.Delete&& Serv!=ser.View)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"\nInvalid Input Try Again!"<<endl<<endl;
        goto Err;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Serv==ser.Add)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Name Of The Student :";
            string Name;
            cin>>Name;
            ReGen:
            cout<<endl<<"Gender Of The Student :";
            string Gender;
            cin>>Gender;
            transform(Gender.begin(), Gender.end(), Gender.begin(), ::tolower);
            if(Gender!="male" && Gender!="female")
            {
                goto ReGen;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\nAge Of The Student :";
                int Age;
                cin>>Age;
                Res:
                if(!cin || Age<0 || Age>20)
                {
                    cout<<endl<<"Age Must Be String & Must Be Greater Than 5 And Lesser Than 20"<<endl;
                    cout<<"\nAge Of The Student :";
                    cin>>Age;
                    if(!cin || Age<0 || Age>20)
                    {
                        goto Res;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<endl<<"Class Of The Student :";
                    int Class;
                    cin>>Class;
                    Res1:
                    if(!cin || Class<=0 || Class>12)
                    {
                        cout<<endl<<"Class Of Student Must Be String & Must Be Greater Than 0 And Lesser Than 12"<<endl;
                        cout<<"\nAge Of The Student :";
                        cin>>Age;
                        if(!cin || Class<1 || Age>12)
                        {
                            goto Res1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Student ID1(Name,Gender,Age,Class);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

What this code does is:-

- It takes the input of all necessary things like **Name, Age, Gender, Class**.
- So what I want to do is to create the instance of the class using the **name** of the student.

Comment: You are looking for `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`)

Comment: "Please ignore the code it's my first week in c++ and please let me know my mistakes in this code." - Please, do not use `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Explore data structures such as [`sets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and [`maps`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in Cpp.**
2. Apart from a thousand possible solutions of this problem, here is one:

```
class Student{
    string name = "no_student";
    /* appropriate members */
};

map<string, Student> m; // mapping from string-name to Student-objects

\\ ADDING A STUDENT:
    m[name] = Student(name, age, gender, class); \\ Appropriately define a constructor.

\\ Finding a student through name:
    Student x = m[name];
    if(m[name] == "no_student"){
        /* NO STUDENT FOUND CASE*/
    }
    else{
        /* ACCESS STUDENT IN X */
    }

\\ Removing an element:
    /* figure out on your own */
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **maps** explore it now (: